# How to compare two lists in R

Tags: r, list, compare

I have two lists that I want to compare. I want to see if the values of each element of the list are equal or not.

```
> m1
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
integer(0)

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 2 3 4

> m3
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 4

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 3

[[5]]
[1] 1 4
```

And I expect a result like this:

```
> Result
[[1]]
[1]
FALSE

[[2]]
[1] 
FALSE TRUE

[[3]]
[1]
FALSE

[[4]]
[1]
FALSE

[[5]]
[1] 
FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

If I try to apply `m1[1] == m3[1]` or similar, I get messages as

> Error in m1 == m3 : comparison of these types is not implemented.

I don't manage to do that simple thing! Thanks for your help in advance.

##### Data

```r
m1 <- list(integer(0), 3:4, integer(0), 1, 2:4)
m3 <- list(3, c(1, 4), 2, 3, c(1, 4))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map`(or `mapply`) with `%in%`.

```
Map(`%in%`, m1, m3)

# [[1]]
# logical(0)
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
# 
# [[3]]
# logical(0)
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] FALSE
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, `m1` contains `integer(0)`, which makes `%in%` return `logical(0)` instead of `FALSE`. So you need to convert `logical(0)` to `FALSE` afterward.

```
res <- Map(`%in%`, m1, m3)
res[lengths(res) == 0] <- FALSE
res

# [[1]]
# [1] FALSE
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] FALSE
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] FALSE
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

##### Update

Another one-liner solution:

```r
Map(\(x, y) x[seq_len(max(1, length(x)))] %in% y, m1, m3)
```

Note: `integer(0)[1]` is `NA` and `NA %in% y` returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the `purrr` library to get your desired output, that examines each element. I used `%in%` instead of `==` if `NAs` exist. Also this assumes each list has the same structure to work.

```
library(purrr)
purrr::map2(m1, m3, function(x, y) x %in% y)
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match the expected one. In addition, you have run `library(purrr)` so that `purrr::xxx` is not needed.

Comment: I did not anticipate that `integer(0)` would result in `logical(0)` so that is my fault

Answer (score 2):

Both Darren and EJJ decided to go along and use `%*%`

If we don't mind the default behaviour of NA in boolean comparison, we can use a simple `for-loop` or `lapply`

```
lapply(seq(la), function(i)a[[i]] == b[[i]])
```

If we want some security that the lists are 'matchable' we can compare their outer and inner lengths and wrap this in a function as below

```
compare_each_list_element <- function(a, b){
  la <- length(lla <- lengths(a))
  lb <- length(llb <- lengths(b))
  if(la != lb || any(lla != llb)){
    warning('Either length(a) != length(b) or some length within a is not equal to some length within b!')
    return(FALSE)
  }
  lapply(seq(la), function(i)a[[i]] == b[[i]])
}
compare_each_list_element(list(1:3, 2, c(3, 2)), list(1:3, 3, c(2, NA)))
[[1]]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

The `compare()` function in {[waldo](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/10/waldo/)} makes it very easy to compare lists or data frames. In this case:

```r
m1 = list(integer(), c(3,4), integer(), 1, c(2, 3, 4))
m3 = list(3, c(1,4), 2, 3, c(1, 4))

waldo::compare(m1, m3, x_arg = "m1", y_arg = "m3")
#> `m1[[1]]` is an integer vector ()
#> `m3[[1]]` is a double vector (3)
#> 
#> `m1[[2]]`: 3 4
#> `m3[[2]]`: 1 4
#> 
#> `m1[[3]]` is an integer vector ()
#> `m3[[3]]` is a double vector (2)
#> 
#> `m1[[4]]`: 1
#> `m3[[4]]`: 3
#> 
#> `m1[[5]]`: 2 3 4
#> `m3[[5]]`: 1   4
```

The console output is color coded:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>